# Play! 1.2.5.: Object's collection of enums binding to template

Tags: java, groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am building a web application in Play! 1.2.5. I have a model class where one of the attributes is a Set collection of enums:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AppUser")
public class User extends Model {

    ...

    @Column(name = "industry_id")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Industry.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "Industry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AppUser_id"))
    public Set<Industry> industries = new HashSet<Industry>();

}
```

The enum is:

```
public enum Industry {
    Industry1,
    Industry2
}
```

How exactly can I bind the `industries` collection to an edit template where the `industries` field is represented as a list of checkboxes, and their checking or unchecking adds them or removes them from the objects collection?

Thany you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your checkboxes like this

```
#{form @save()}
<input type="checkbox" value="Industry1" name="user.industries">Industry number 1
<input type="checkbox" value="Industry2" name="user.industries">Industry number 2
<input type="checkbox" value="Industry3" name="user.industries">Industry number 3
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
#{/form}
```

In my case it works on a model without JPA annotations but I guess it also work in your case

Comment: With trial and error, this is exactly what I came up with in the end. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Having done that recently, I offer you the following solution:

In the controller, you pass the Enum as an `Iterator` to the view:

```
Iterator<Attribute> industries = EnumSet.allOf(Industry.class).iterator();
render(industries);
```

In your form view, you iterate through the list and check what is selected:

```
#{list items: industries, as: 'industry' }
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="industries" value="${industry.name()}"
        #{if user?.industries?.contains(industry)} checked #{/if}
     />
     &{'industry'}
</label>
#{/list}
```

To handle the case when no field is selected, you need the following (as, when nothing is selected, no value will be submitted, and the existing selection will stay:

```
<input type="hidden" name="industries" value="" />
```

Finally, in your controller method receiving the form input, it suffices to have a parameter `Set<Industry> industries` into which Play will load the selected values.

Comment: Thank you very much, but Seb's answer works for my scenario. The controller in my case returns renderTemplate(user) with the whole object, not just the industries collection.

Comment: You asked for a solution for "and their checking or unchecking adds them or removes them from the objects collection", use cases which are handled by my solution, but not with Sebs. Duplicating the Enum in the view violates DRY and is bad practice, meriting passing in the whole EnumSet additionally.

Comment: I agree about the DRY principle, but in my case nothing is duplicated with custom template tags and so on. Example from a tag: <input type="checkbox" value="${value}" name="${id}" #{if selected} checked="checked" #{/if} />

Comment: I argue about duplicating the code for the Enum values, not of the input tag.